# Grails 3.3.6 Does not come with GORM Configured?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails3

I had to upgrade a grails plugin from 2.3.11 to 3.3.6. When I was testing the finished port I noticed errors on my GORM queries. If I recall, in grails 2 GORM already came with it. Is that not the case in grails 3.3.6 ? What do I need to do to enable GORM? I will mention that I am using a SQL Server datasource. Here is the error I get from grails console doing a simple `Person.first()`

```
Exception thrown

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [comp.Person] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.stateException(GormEnhancer.groovy:469)

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findStaticApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:300)

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findStaticApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:296)

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.currentGormStaticApi(GormEntity.groovy:1368)

    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)

    at comp.Person.currentGormStaticApi(Person.groovy)

    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.first(GormEntity.groovy:720)

    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$first.call(Unknown Source)

    at comp.Person.first(Person.groovy)

    at comp.Person$first.call(Unknown Source)

    at ConsoleScript1.run(ConsoleScript1:3)

    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
```

In my `gradle.properties` file it says `gormVersion=6.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

And here is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.2"

    }
}

version "2.0-SNAPSHOT"
group "pluginmigration"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin-publish"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {

    //compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.10"
    //compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:3.0.2'
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web-plugin"
    provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.2"
    runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

// enable if you wish to package this plugin as a standalone application
bootRepackage.enabled = false
grailsPublish {
    // TODO: Provide values here
    user = 'user'
    key = 'key'
    githubSlug = 'foo/bar'
    license {
        name = 'Apache-2.0'
    }
    title = "My Plugin"
    desc = "Full plugin description"
    developers = [johndoe:"John Doe"]
}



assets {
    packagePlugin = true
}
```

EDIT: Here is the stacktrace error I get when I include the hibernate dependencies:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/
ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
 [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at pluginmigration.Application.main(Application.groovy:7)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:931)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:808)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.B
eanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerExcept
ion
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceSettings$HibernateSettings.populateProperties(HibernateConnectionSourceSettings.groovy:258)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceSettings$HibernateSettings.populateProperties(HibernateConnectionSourceSettings.groovy:255)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceSettings$HibernateSettings.populateProperties(HibernateConnectionSourceSettings.groovy:255)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceSettings$HibernateSettings.toProperties(HibernateConnectionSourceSettings.groovy:246)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceSettings$HibernateSettings$toProperties.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceSettings.toProperties(HibernateConnectionSourceSettings.groovy:51)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.buildConfiguration(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:242)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:85)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

EDIT2: As requested, my datasource block in `application.yml` has been included (also have hibernate incase it matters):

```
---
hibernate:
  cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory


  environments:
    development:
      dataSources:
        one:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
          logSql: true
          formatSql: true
          driverClassName: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
          dbCreate: none
          url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1804/one
          username: u
          password: p

        two:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
          logSql: true
          formatSql: true
          driverClassName: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
          dbCreate: none
          url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1804/two
          username: u
          password: p

        three:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
          logSql: true
          formatSql: true
          driverClassName: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
          dbCreate: none
          url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1804/three
          username: u
          password: p

    test:
      dataSources:
    production:
      dataSources:
```

Comment: You have your GORM Hibernate5 plugin commented out. If you aren't using that one you need to pick one of the other implementations from http://gorm.grails.org/.

Comment: I get a stacktrace error when I uncomment those lines.

Comment: Your stacktrace is because there is a problem with your datasource.  Show your environments { development { datasource block from application.groovy or application.yml.

Comment: @Daniel My datasource is in application.yml. However I also have application.groovy (this plugin is a migration from grails 2). Does that matter?

Comment: @Daniel I added the datasources.

Comment: @Bmoe Two things.  1. you probably don't want your datasources defined in your plugin, but rather in the application that uses the plugin. (other than in test, I mean) 2. You may need to have a look at the Gorm manual's section on multiple data sources (currently https://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#multipleDataSources)

Comment: @npskirk this plugin can function as a standalone application. As a matter of fact when I used grails 2, I did all of my testing within the plugin. I didn't care about the datasources because they don't get bundled up when I package the plugin.

Also in that link you provided, I noticed that the official grails documentation conflicts with it. In the gorm manual, you put the default datasource on top. In the grails manual it goes underneath the datasources block. Haven't gotten either to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using `REALEASE`version instead of `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` one, this issue has been fixed in [v3.3.7](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11033), so all you have to do is replace:

```
gormVersion=6.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

with

```
gormVersion=6.1.10.RELEASE
```

in your `gradle.properties` file then rebuild the project again.

Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your dependencies on hibernate commented out?  Uncomment them or add a different version if necessary.

Comment: Daniel, I get a stacktrace error when including the hibernate depedencies:

Answer (score 0):

My project is Grails 3.3.5

```
grailsVersion=3.3.5
grailsWrapperVersion=1.0.0
gormVersion=6.1.8.RELEASE
gradleWrapperVersion=3.5
```

So you'll need to make version adjustments, but...

I notice that your buildfile is for a grails plugin.  In my plugin project it is working when set up like so:

```
# Note: no hibernate related dependencies in the 'compile' configuration

testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
testCompile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
```

Notice, no version specifier on the hibernate plugin.

Then in my application that uses my plugin, I have a buildscript block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.energizedwork.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:1.4"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.energizedwork:idea-gradle-plugins:1.4"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion - ".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.6"
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.3'
    }
}
```

Here notice that the ".RELEASE' is subtracted from the gormVersion in the gradle.properties.  In your case I guess you'd have to subtract ".BUILD-SNAPSHOT"

Finally in the regular project dependencies I have:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
```

along with my other dependencies.

This is working fine in my project.

Comment: are you actually using GORM commands in your plugin though? That's what I'm doing. It isn't working. I copied your setup besides the grails version. I don't know what db (if at all) you use in the plugin but I have sql server setup (`runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.0'`)

Comment: The plugin does interact with the database (with gorm), it contains both domain objects and services.  In test I use H2, in production I use MySQL.